# Adding value to text Box goes to exception "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, telerik-reporting

I am working on a .NET project in which i should get data from a web service and then show this data in a telerik report. The thing is that my code goes to exception "object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
        public CertifikatePersonale(string ssn)
    {
        string COUNTY = null;
        string FATHER_NAME = null;
        try
        {
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            SkyServices service = new SkyServices();
            object [] merrcertifikate = getPerCertificate(ssn);
            for (int i = 0; i < merrcertifikate.Length; i++)
             {
                 string SSN = ((string)(merrcertifikate[1]));
                 string LAST_NAME = ((string)(merrcertifikate[2]));
                  FATHER_NAME = ((string)(merrcertifikate[3]));
                 string ADDRESS = ((string)(merrcertifikate[4]));
                 string GENDER = ((string)(merrcertifikate[5]));
                 string BIRTH_PLACE = ((string)(merrcertifikate[6]));
                 string BIRTH_DATE = ((string)(merrcertifikate[7]));
                 string MOTHER_NAME = ((string)(merrcertifikate[8]));
                 string MARITAL_STATUS = ((string)(merrcertifikate[9]));
                  COUNTY = ((string)(merrcertifikate[10]));
                 string DOCUMENT_TYPE = ((string)(merrcertifikate[11]));
                 string DOCUMENT_ISSUE_DATE = ((string)(merrcertifikate[12]));
                 string DOCUMENT_EXPIRATION_DATE = ((string)(merrcertifikate[13]));
                 string RESPONSE = ((string)(merrcertifikate[14]));
                 string RESPONSE_DATA = ((string)(merrcertifikate[15]));

            }
          txb_Nation.Value = COUNTY.ToString().ToUpper();

        }
        catch { }
    }
```

the row

```
      txb_Nation.Value = COUNTY.ToString().ToUpper();
```

leads to exception even that County has a value. 
Please help, this is taking more time than it should. Thank you

Comment: What happens when u remove the try and catch part? Also, you could try merrcertifikate[1].ToString(), instead of casting it to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `COUNTY` really has a value, then it must be `txb_Nation` that's not initialized. Your code does not show where that reference comes from; check if its value is properly set.

Comment: you are right. i had not called inialize function inside this method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
txb_Nation.Value = COUNTY==null?"":COUNTY.ToString().ToUpper();
```